# Unable to download image in SD Card open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: android

```
package com.rovedashcam.android.view.common.activity;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import com.rovedashcam.android.R;
import com.rovedashcam.android.view.base.BaseActivity;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class NewUploadPhoto extends BaseActivity {
    File directory;
    String downloadLink = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/charly1811/google-books-api-android-sample/master/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png";
    String fileName;
    String folderName;
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_upload);
        folderName = "RoveDashCam/Photos";

        createFolderForApp(folderName);

    }


    private void createFolderForApp(String FolderName) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES) + "/" + FolderName);
        } else {
            directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + FolderName);
        }
        Log.i("TAG", "createFolderForApp: " + directory.getPath());
        if (!directory.exists()) {
            boolean success = directory.mkdirs();
            if (!success) {
                directory = null;
            } else {
                new FileDownloader().execute(downloadLink);
            }
        } else {
            new FileDownloader().execute(downloadLink);
        }
    }

    private class FileDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showProgressDialog();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result = "";
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(downloadLink)) {
                String MY_URL = downloadLink;
                try {
                    result = downloadFile(MY_URL);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "doInBackground: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            } else {
            }
            return result;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            hideProgressDialog();
            Toast.makeText(NewUploadPhoto.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private String downloadFile(String MY_URL) {
        int count;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(MY_URL);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
            fileName = MY_URL.substring(MY_URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, MY_URL.length());
            File outputFile = new File(directory, fileName);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                int status = (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
                new Handler().post(() -> {
                  showProgressDialog();
                    if (status == 100) {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                });
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            return "Downloaded at: " + directory.getPath() + fileName;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Abhan", "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            runOnUiThread(() -> hideProgressDialog());
        }
        hideProgressDialog();
        return "Downloading Error";
    }
}
```

This is my code i am trying to download image in SD card in given folder "RoveDashCam/Photos" but when  i am getting error
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/RoveDashCam/Photos/ic_launcher.png: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

I have already given permission of write external and image read video read permission  then also i am getting error can any one please help me in this what i am doing wrong with this code how i can download image to sdCard in android .
This is happening only android 13  phone. android 10 i have checked i was able to download .

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/ is not an sd card. Has nothing to do with a removable micro sd card. Please adapt your post.

Comment: Thanks for response can you please help me  how to   download  image in specific folder in android

Comment: Please reread my first comment and do it.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks i understand but can you please help me where i have to save in specific folder ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create image files in the public Movies directories on Android 11+ devices.

Only video files.

Comment: Thanks for answer but what will be solution what we need to change can you please suggest me

Comment: The solution is not to save as image file but as video file.

Comment: Yes i am able to save video file but suppose i have to save image file in specific folder then how i will do

Comment: You save image files in image folders and video files in video folders and audio files in audio folders. You can save any file in public Download and Documents folders.